# how to get a static file (.json) palced in myapp/apps/myapp/jsons/ through SC.Request.getUrl

Tags: sproutcore

My sprout core app name is myapp. My directory structure is myapp/apps/myapp/.
I have created a directory named jsons inside myapp/apps/myapp/, and placed a file called emp.json, I want to get this file through ajax using SC.Request.getUrl. I tried the following but didn't work. I want to know the url to reach out this file.

```
SC.Request.getUrl('/myapp/apps/myapp/resources/emp.json').notify(this, this.didFetchContacts)
.send();

SC.Request.getUrl('/myapp/resources/emp.json').notify(this, this.didFetchContacts)
.send();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you will need to use static_url. So if emp.json is in your resources directory, you can call this:

```
    SC.Request.getUrl(static_url('emp.json')).notify(this, this.didFetchContacts)
              .send();
```

NOTE: This is not a javascript function. The compiler will replace this with the location of the file in the built app

Comment: Thanks, its working. I also have one more clarification. I placed my emp.json in myapp/apps/myapp/resources/jsons/, and made     SC.Request.getUrl(static_url('jsons/emp.json')).notify(this, this.didFetchContacts)
    .send(); . When i looked into the firebug console the request url was  http://localhost:4020/static/myapp/en/current/resources/jsons/emp.json?1309932342. My doubt is from where did this en,current folders came in between the resources folder. Thanks again for the solution.

Comment: you can publish your sproutcore app in multiple languages so it appends the langauge code, en for english in this case. In addition, once you build your app, it will generate a folder structure with a GUID to force a re-cache from the browser.